# PHP Remove url-"not allowed" characters from string

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have read through all the questions regarding this, and would like to know if `$str = preg_replace('/[^\00-\255]+/u', '', $str);` is sufficient for my scenario.

**My Scenario**

When a user creates an account on my site, he enters his company's name. This can be anything including text with `'` or `"` or even some other strange characters. When he creates an account, I need to create a folder on my server for him to access his account easier without using `uniqids` etc.

So for example you create an account for "Peter's Pet Shop & Washing" - I would need to remove all spaces and characters that would not be allowed as a url-address. So at the end I need to have "peterspetshopwashing"

This is so that you can access your account at "www.mydomain.com/peterspetshopwashing"

Comment: Be careful though because "Peter's Pets Hop @ Washing" would also translate to the same string.

Comment: Yep, noticed that. Will be checking that the input must be unique

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I currently use this function I'm happy with

```
function url($url) {
   $url = preg_replace('~[^\\pL0-9_]+~u', '-', $url);
   $url = trim($url, "-");
   $url = iconv("utf-8", "us-ascii//TRANSLIT", $url);
   $url = strtolower($url);
   $url = preg_replace('~[^-a-z0-9_]+~', '', $url);
   return $url;
}
```

it replaces spaces and other odd characters with `-` so result will be `peter-s-pet-shop-washing`

Comment: Sweet, I tuned it a bit, making `'` go away instead of `-` Thank you.